# Emberjs- Creating a new entity from two models

Tags: ember.js

I have an ember application with two models, `user` and `subject`. Data related to the user and subject comes from a REST api. Each user can be associated with a number of subjects. I am trying to make a create user template in which you can input details about the user, name, email etc, and then choose a number of subjects that this user studies. The subjects need to be populated by a get request to the api but I can't figure out how to access them here. Can anyone help? Here is what I've tried-

```
<script type = "text/x-handlebars" id = "user/create">

<div class="input-group">

<h2>Create Template</h2>

  <h5>First Name</h5>
  {{input value=firstName}}

  <h5>Last Name</h5>
  {{input value=lastName}}

  <h5>Email</h5>
  {{input value=email}}

  <h5>Subjects</h5>

    <ul class="list-group">
{{#each subject in subjectsController}}
  <label>
        {{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding="selected"}}
        {{name}}
    </label><br />
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

User model-

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  firstName    : DS.attr('string'),
  lastName     : DS.attr('string'),
  email        : DS.attr('string'),
  subjects    : DS.hasMany('subject')


});
```

Subject Model-

```
App.Subject = DS.Model.extend({
  name         : DS.attr('string'),
  users: DS.hasMany('user')
});
```

EDIT: updated template

```
<script type = "text/x-handlebars" id = "user/create">

<div class="input-group">

<h2>Create Template</h2>

  <h5>First Name</h5>
  {{input value=firstName}}

  <h5>Last Name</h5>
  {{input value=lastName}}

  <h5>Email</h5>
  {{input value=email}}

  <h5>Subjects</h5>

    <ul class="list-group">
{{#each subject in usersCreateController}}
  <label>
        {{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding="selected"}}
        {{name}}
    </label><br />
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

and usersCreateController-

```
App.UsersCreateController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

subjects: function(){
    return this.store.find('subjects');
  }.property()


  actions: {
    save: function(){
      // just before saving, we set the creationDate
      this.get('model').set('creationDate', new Date());

      // create a record and save it to the store
      var newUser = this.store.createRecord('user', this.get('model'));
      newUser.save();

      // redirects to the user itself
      this.transitionToRoute('user', newUser);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the `UserCreateController` add a computed property that fetches them.

```
App.UserCreateController = Em.Controller.extend({
  subjects: function(){
    return this.store.find('subjects');
  }.property()
});

{{#each subject in subjects}}
  <label>
        {{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding="selected"}}
        {{subject.name}}
    </label><br />
{{/each}}
```

Comment: thanks but that hasn't had any effect..I will try and put it in a jsfiddle

Comment: You'll need to update the handlebars as well to point to the new property

Comment: It's still not getting them, and oddly enough there is no error in console

Comment: will you add {{subjects.length}} outside of the each loop